# Expression evaluator in sql query SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

I have this query

```
Declare @q varchar(255) = 'A+B'

Select
A, -- 1
B, -- 2
C,
Evaluate(@q) MySum -- 3
From tbl_temp
```

Assuming the @q is also a column from tbl_temp

Is there any method sql that do something like that?

I have in mind, a function that accepts the expression and also the columns. Just asking if there's a better way than this.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create CLR function to evaluate expressions:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess=DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static object Evaluate(SqlString expression, SqlString values)
{
    string[] variables = values.Value.Split(',');

    Dictionary<string, string> vars = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach(string var in variables)
    {
        string[] varAndValue = var.Split('=');

        vars.Add(varAndValue[0], varAndValue[1]);
    }

    string expr = expression.Value;

    foreach(string var in vars.Keys)
    {
        expr = expr.Replace(var, vars[var]);
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT {0}", expr), connection);
        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        return result;
    }
}
```

then use it in sql as follow:

```
declare @t table(A int, B int, Expr varchar(max))
insert into @t(A,B,Expr)
select 5,6, 'A+B' union all
select 1,2, 'A*B' 

select dbo.Evaluate(Expr, 'A=' + cast(A as varchar) + ',' + 'B=' + cast(B as varchar))
from @t
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval SQL.NET](http://eval-sql.net/)

There is no "eval" method in SQL however this can be easily done using Eval SQL.NET Library.

```
-- CREATE expression
DECLARE @sqlnet SQLNET = SQLNET::New('A+B')

-- EVALUATE expression from a table
SELECT @sqlnet.SetValue('A', A).SetValue('B', B).Eval()
FROM tbl_temp
```

Documentation: [Dynamically evaluate arithmetic operation and expression in SQL](http://eval-sql.net/arithmetic-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is no.  There is no easy way to do this.  In general, if you have such expressions, then you would use dynamic SQL to parse them.  And, you cannot use dynamic SQL in a function.

This leaves you two basic options.  The first is to use your own parsing routine, probably in a CLR (written in an external language).  This is a feasible approach if you really have a need for this functionality.

The second is to use one of the stored procedures that you are allowed to use in a function:  `xp_cmdshell`.  Note:  using this stored procedure is not recommended as a general solution, because of security issues and special permissions.  Also, getting the value calculated from the stored procedure requires some cleverness (essentially echo out the results into a pre-defined table variable).